# How to read excel file data each cell and save that data into database table as per the column name

Tags: java, database

I am trying to read excel file data and saving that data into the database.
data is comming to console. I have two column in excel file namely Userid and RequestId  I am trying to save the data similarly in the database table in the same manner.
Data is going in the table but both columns are having same value.
I need them seperately.I am using this code for reading.

```
    FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(new File("C://excel.xls"));
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file2);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            rowIterator.next();
           while(rowIterator.hasNext())

            {

                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

double value2=(int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
  System.out.println("value1: "+value2);
  }`
```

In console it is showing correctly but the data is not going in that manner in database

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: More interesting woud be your code to write the values into the database.

Answer (score 0):

With some `Data` class:

```
class Data {
    private final double val1;
    private final double val2;

    public Data(final double val1; final double val2) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

    // getters etc
}
```

and

```
final List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Row r : sheet) {
    // Maybe skip an header row
    final Cell cell1 = r.getCell(0); // 0-based
    final Cell cell2 = r.getCell(1);
    if (cell1 != null && cell2 != null) {
        datas.add(new Data(cell1.getNumericCellValue(), cell2.getNumericCellValue()));
    }
}

// TODO: write datas to DB
```

**NB: wild code (i.e. didn't even try to compile it)**

Some reading: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator